# Multiplicative Inverse in $S=\{a+b\sqrt{2} \mid a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove that $S=\{a+b\sqrt{2} \mid a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$ is a field and so far everything worked out for me except for finding the multiplicative inverse over $(S\backslash\{0\}, \cdot)$ which is:
$$\forall a \in S: \exists (a^{-1}) \in S: a\cdot(a^{-1})=1$$

As a proof I thought of: $(a+b\sqrt{2}) \cdot (a+b\sqrt{2})^{-1} \Rightarrow (a+b\sqrt{2}) \cdot \frac{1}{(a+b\sqrt{2})}$ but I am stuck with the fraction. It is non-trivial for me to compute the inverse of an element $a \in S$.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Rationalize the denominator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  You want $c,d \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $c + d \sqrt{2} = \frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}}$ for any $a,b \in \Bbb{Q}$.  Have you tried rationalizing the denominator on the right (using its [conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(square_roots)))?

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, that is a really good hint! So basically:
$$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1 \cdot (a-b\sqrt{2})}{(a+b\sqrt{2}) \cdot (a-b\sqrt{2})}=\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}-(\frac{b}{a^2-2b^2})\sqrt{2}$$
if I made no mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: from the difference of squares factorization $(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})=a^2-2b^2$.